# Run sails.js on a specific IP address during development

Tags: javascript, ip, sails.js, sandbox

I am new to **sails.js** and trying to develop a simple app on a remote sandbox server. When I do `'sails lift'` to test running the app, I cannot access it by `'localhost'`.

I am wondering what's the right way of running sails on a **specific IP during development**. I tried `'sails lift --ip xxx.xxx.xx.xx'`, but it does not work, and the documentation on this seems lacking.

Does anyone know how to run sails.js on an IP without needing deployment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `local.js` in config directoty to add this config:

    `{
      host: your_ip,
      port: your_port
    }`

Or add `port` and `host` in `config/env/development.js`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for Sails 1.x, as host is deprecated in new version, so new name for specifying host is, "explicitHost".

So one can mention in `config/env/development.js`

> explicitHost: 'your_ip_Address'

> port: 'your_port_number'

For more, [sails documentation for these kind of settings](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config)